# No entry point specified on dll.manifest in Mageui.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dll, manifest

I am trying to use MageUI.exe included in Visual Studio 2008 on a DLL in order to deploy it. When I try to save the application manifest I got the "Files page - No entry point specified" message every time. If I set on the Files Tab a dll as Entry Point, it is not a valid Entry Point. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there's a valid entry point? Usually the entry point is `static void Main(string[] a) {...}` so you want to be running Mage against the folder that contains the assembly or executable that runs Main. Unless it's a COM dll in which case it gets a bit more complicated...